# Laravel password reset without using user email - using angular as front end

Tags: php, angular, laravel, passwords

I'm developing laravel-angular application and i do want to do a password reset facility , but laravel default password-reset  required email to do the same. But this application dosent want such an option , using email to reset the password . I Just set `$confirmEmail` to `false` but its not seems like working . 
Is there any other ways to figure it out..
Any help would be really appreciated . thanks

Comment: if you don't want to use email for reset password then how do you want to implement it ?

Comment: I don't want to force the users to enter the email id again, would like to do by just entering 'password' and 'confirm password' like so.

Answer (score -1):

Just use your variable $email to the view/blade

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
//just use the $email variable in your blade file or so.
```

Comment: I think it wont help me out. I'm working with API , i setup  all the thing but dont want to use the email for reset- password

Comment: Then post your api controller method here which is being used for reset password